# Can the compiler verify a generic type of an object through a generic method?

Tags: java, generics, enums

First of all, sorry for the bad title. I don't know how to describe the problem in a few words (maybe not even in many)...

I am refactoring some settings in our system to be more abstract. The current solution has multiple tables in the DB, one for each settings area. In order to add a new setting, you'll need to extend the schema, the hibernate class, all transfer object classes, getters/setters, etc. I felt that this is violating OCP (open-closed principle), thus the refactoring.

I've spent some time coming up with ideas on how to implement such an abstraction. My favourite idea so far is the following:

- 1 enum for each settings area
- 1 enum value for each setting
- Each setting is a `SettingsDefinition<T>` class using a generic type
- A `SettingsService` is using static get/set methods with generic types

So for example, a settings area could be:

```
public enum SettingsABC{
    A(new SettingDefinition<Integer>("A", 123)),
    B(new SettingDefinition<String>("B", "Hello")),
    C(new SettingDefinition<Boolean>("C", false));

    private SettingDefinition settingDefinition;

    SettingsABC(SettingDefinition settingDefinition) {
            this.settingDefinition = settingDefinition;
    }

    public SettingDefinition getDefinition() {
            return settingDefinition;
    }
}
```

Where the `SettingDefinition` is the following:

```
public class SettingDefinition<T> {
    private String name;
    private T defaultValue;

    public SettingDefinition(String name, T defaultValue) {
            this.name = name;
            this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public T getDefaultValue() {
            return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

And the service to get/set the values would be:

```
public class SettingsService {
    public static <T> T getSetting(SettingDefinition setting) {
            // hit db to read
            // return value
    }

    public static <T> void setSetting(SettingDefinition setting, T value) {
            // hit db to write
    }
}
```

And the consumer would look something like this:

```
String value = SettingsService.getSetting(SettingsABC.B.getDefinition());
SettingsService.setSetting(SettingsABC.A.getDefinition(), 123);
```

My problem is that I cannot enforce a compiler type check between the generic type of the `SettingDefinition` inside `SettingsABC` and the generic type of get/set methods of the service. So in essence, I can do this:

```
Integer value = SettingsService.getSetting(SettingsABC.B.getDefinition());
```

Where `B`'s definition is of type `String`.

Also, I can do this:

```
SettingsService.setSetting(SettingsABC.A.getDefinition(), "A");
```

Where `A`'s definition is an `Integer`.

Is there any way to use generics to force these two different generic types match?

Comment: Won't `public static <T> void setSetting(SettingDefinition<T> setting, T value)` work?

Comment: I would expect it would, but it doesn't. I'm not that experienced in Generics so I cannot explain why not.

Comment: You need to store/pass the `Class<T>` yourself. Then the getter can do `return clazz.cast(value);`. = your own runtime storage of the class.

Comment: I see raw types! *Never* use just the types when describing generic classes. Even the ability to do so is an archaic backwards compatibility mess. You can always do something like `GenericType<?>`.

Comment: I'm sorry mate, I don't understand how this will replace raw types. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the enum to the class:

```
public final class SettingsABC<T> {
    public static final SettingsABC<Integer> A = 
               new SettingsABC<>(new SettingDefinition<>("A", 123));
    public static final SettingsABC<String> B = 
               new SettingsABC<>(new SettingDefinition<>("B", "Hello"));
    public static final SettingsABC<Boolean> C = 
               new SettingsABC<>(new SettingDefinition<>("C", false));

    private final SettingDefinition<T> settingDefinition;

    // private constructor, so nobody else would instantiate it
    private SettingsABC(SettingDefinition<T> settingDefinition) {
            this.settingDefinition = settingDefinition;
    }

    public SettingDefinition<T> getDefinition() {
            return settingDefinition;
    }
}
```

This way individual constants will be typed. Now you can use the type arguments for `SettingService` as well:

```
public static <T> T getSetting(SettingDefinition<T> setting) {
    ...
}

public static <T> void setSetting(SettingDefinition<T> setting, T value) {
    ...
}
```

Although it's not an enum anymore, it can be used mostly in the same way. If you need other methods which are usually available in enum, you can mimic them like this:

```
public String name() {
    return settingDefinition.getName();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return settingDefinition.getName();
}
// and so on
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be closer to what I had in mind. I'll look into it further. <3